# Finding and representing area between nested, non-intersecting polygons

Tags: java, math, polygon

Given two `java.awt.Polygon` objects `p1` and `p2`, how would I go about determining (and representing) the area between them?

[image: sample image]

I would like to find the gray area within in-between the polygons. The polygons are arbitrary and the only information I have about them are their points (x,y).

The answer might be staring right at me but I've been trying to come up with a solution for >2 hours in vain now so any and all pointers will be much appreciated!

Edit: the first thing I tried was representing both polygons as one but that resulted in an unusable mess of intersections.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Do you want to compute the area or represent the resulting shape?

Comment: Represent the resulting shape, ideally in a way that would allow me to access points from within said shape.

Comment: Does one necessarily contain the other? If not, how would you define the area "between" them?

Comment: What do you mean by "allow me to access points from within"? Do you want to check if a point is in the area? If so, then `if (p_1.contains(point) && ! p_2.contains(point))`

Comment: I'm not failiar with `java.awt.Polygon`; does it represent the polygon as an ordered list of vertices? If so, then there is a standard way to represent a non-simple polygon like the boundary of the region between `p_1` and `p_2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert both of these polygons into [`Area`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html)s, and then do a `subtract` from there.